# Error when trying to run spring boot jar file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to run a spring boot jar file with java -jar on a windows system.

Below are the steps that i have followed

1. Created a simple Spring Boot project with Maven as build tool
2. Update pom.xml to use spring-boot-maven-plugin to bundle dependencies in jar file
3. Create a jar file using mvn clean install and try to run the jar.

It fails with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/support/AopUtils
    at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.resolveDeclaredEventType(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.<init>(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.supportsEvent(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:287)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:221)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:192)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:292)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.csh.SpringBootApp.main(SpringBootApp.java:26)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52)
    at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Have you added AOP dependency?

Comment: Yes, i tried adding below dependency

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/support/AopUtils` is missing

Comment: Yes, so what can I do to resolve it? I have added spring aop dependency and tried.

Comment: Try deleting the `spring-aop` jar from Maven's cache and rebuilding your application. The jar may be corrupted.